# supervise/daemontools conflicts with apache -D FOREGROUND

Tags: apache-2.2, daemontools

Hoping that somebody can help us understand this behavior.

We've got a bunch of daemontools services under /etc/service/.  One of the services controls apache, and the run script has this in it.

```
exec envdir /var/lib/supervise/wwwproxy/env setuidgid root bash <<-BASH
    ulimit -n 8192  # also increase the running user's file descriptor limit
    exec apache2 -f /path/to/demo_apache2.conf -D FOREGROUND
BASH
```

We were having the problem that `svc -d /etc/service/*` actually had the effect of restarting all the services, it didn't take them down.  We finally tracked it down to that one service, and found that `svc -d /etc/service/apache2` would bring *up* any other service was down, including itself.

Changing FOREGROUND to NO_DAEMONIZE fixes the behavior, but we'd really like to understand what's going on.  Can anybody explain why an `svc -d` on *one* service would bring an *other* service up?

Thanks for any clue you can offer.

Comment: Why aren't you just using an initd script?

Comment: ---Can you post the run script you're using for Apache?--- <-Nevermind, I'm blind :-) Also, can you tell us why in the name of everything unholy you're using `supervise` to control Apache? (Apache does its own process management, and it does a good job of it. You're almost certainly better off with a watchdog script than trying to hack together a solution with daemontools...)

Answer (score 2):

For me `-D NO_DAEMONIZE` didn't work, I had to use `-D NO_DETACH`. (CentOS 6.3, Apache/2.2.15)

See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html:

> Also can be used to set certain less-common startup parameters
>   including -DNO_DETACH (prevent the parent from forking) and
>   -DFOREGROUND (prevent the parent from calling setsid() et al).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to *not use daemontools to run Apache*, but in lieu of that you should simplify your run script.

Start with the barest of minimums:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec apache2 -f /path/to/httpd.conf -D NO_DAEMONIZE
```

If you need/want to use `envdir` you can start apache with that instead of `exec`.
The `ulimit` call is probably not necessary, but can be added anywhere in the run script before you launch Apache.

---

Re: the actual strange behavior you're seeing, there *are* some functional differences between `-DFOREGROUND` and `-DNO_DAEMONIZE` -- the latter is what I've always seen recommended for running Apache under daemontools (preceded by the obligtory "Don't Do That") -- I don't know why any of those differences would cause the behavior you describe though.